# What is the correct grid-columns declaration?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am confused. I am reading about grids in CSS. I am reading a Microsoft book and they've written the following property:

```css
.container{
    grid-columns: 1;
}
```

But in a video I was watching on YouTube, they wrote:

```css
.container{
    grid-template-columns: 1;
}
```

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grid-columns` is a property in the old and outdated version of the CSS Grid Spec that is supported in IE11 and Edge. `grid-template-columns` is what you should use if you want to learn the new and standardized version of the spec.

I would suggest learning the new one since it launched in Firefox 52 on Tuesday and will be coming to Safari and Chrome shortly (Edge at a later date presumably).

Comment: thanks. i was preparing for microsoft html5 css3 exam. seems to me book is outdated..

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, as MateBoy says is outdated:

"Abandonded WD. The name has been changed to grid-definition-columns in the newer draft “CSS Grid Layout”, but IE 10 implementation is based on the older name: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh772246.aspx"

Answer (score -1):

Like others have said, the MS spec is outdated, but you would want to use the `grid-template-columns` on the element that you have declared a grid on. This sets up the columns that will be available in your grid on that parent element. Then you would use `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end` on a child element to declare the where that elements should be positioned on the grid. Shorthand for that is `grid-column: value / value;`

I have a Pen to show a few ways to write grid-column syntax http://codepen.io/stacy/pen/zodXYp

But here are some options:

```
.foo {
    display: grid;
    // The repeat keyword will iterate how many you declare in the first number, and the second number is the size. The fr is a new unit for grid
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.yay {
    /* Grid Column Available Syntax/Shorthand 
       --------------------------------------*/
    /* 
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-column: 1 / 4; 
    grid-column: 2 / span 3; 
    */
    /* -1 below means to span remaining columns in that row */
    grid-column: 2 / -1; 

    /* Grid Row Available Syntax/Shorthand 
   -----------------------------------*/
    /* 
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2; 
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 2 / -1; 
    */ 


    /* Grid Area shorthand
    grid-area: grid-row-start / grid-column-start / grid-row-end / grid-column-end;
    Can also used named lines if decalred in grid-template-*
    /* grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 3; */
}
```